# How to connect to MySQL using OpenJDK in Linux Mint

Tags: mysql, jdbc, java

I am having issues trying to get a database connection using the code below:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?" + "user=test&password=123456");
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }                                             
}
```

The error message that is outputted is:

```
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?user=test&password=123456
SQLState: 08001
VendorError: 0

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at Demo.main(Demo.java:9)
```

My java version is below:

```
java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java
javac -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/javac
javac.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/man/man1/javac.1.gz
javadoc -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/javadoc
javadoc.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/man/man1/javadoc.1.gz
javah -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/javah
javah.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/man/man1/javah.1.gz
javap -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/javap
javap.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/man/man1/javap.1.gz
javaws -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/javaws
javaws.1.gz -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/man/man1/javaws.1.gz
```

I've, literally, no idea how to troubleshoot this error message. The database exists. The username and password exists. I've currently not added any tables to the database but I don't think that can be the issue, since I'm only making a connection after all...

Driver is installed under /usr/share/java

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   822524 10月 20  2011 mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   827942  9月  9 22:40 mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       35  9月  9 22:40 mysql-connector-java.jar -> mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 10月 20  2011 mysql.jar -> mysql-connector-java.jar
```

Does anybody know how to fix it..
Thanks for your help! 
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have mysql connector driver (i.e. jar file) in your project library. This error message appears when there is no appropriate driver.

You can download the MySQL connector driver [from this site](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Comment: I install the driver, but still has the problem..

Driver is under /usr/share/java/
`code`    
mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar
    mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
    mysql-connector-java.jar -> mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
    mysql.jar -> mysql-connector-java.jar

Comment: Are you using any kind of IDE like eclipse or netbeans??

Comment: it seems like your classpath is not configured properly. so, configure your classpath correctly. try using /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar

Comment: I put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/ext, and everything is ok now !

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and the [curiouss answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12339940/2075782) helped me to figure out an new solution.

Note: I was using Maven.

So I decided to try this dependency: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

After I added into the `pom.xml` and run `mvn compile exec:java`it worked.